# How to call a button on button click recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, button, javafx

How can I add new `Button` on clicking a button for the infinite or dynamic number of times? Or in simple words how can perform the functionality of add more buttons?

I have tried in Javafx, but it only adding the two buttons in list.

```
@FXML
void addMoreButton(ActionEvent event) {

    b[count]=new Button("+");
    b[count].setOnMouseClicked(event2 -> { 
        count++;
        b[count]=new Button("+");
        list.setAll(b[count]);
        vboxTest.getChildren().addAll(list);
    });

    list.add(b[count]);
    vboxTest.getChildren().addAll(list);

}
```

but I have to add dynamically till user wants to add/press the previous button

Comment: Only the previous button should add a button ? What the purpose of the `list` and the `Button` array ?

Comment: Yes, only the last added button should call the next one (means second button call third button , and third call to forth and so on)... I have tried to array for multiple buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> only the last added button should call the next one (means second button call third button , and third call to forth and so on)...

Assuming you start with exactly 1 button using the method as `onAction` event handler, you need to do 2 things to properly update the scene:

1. add a new button using the same event handler
2. remove the event handler from the button clicked

You can do so by accessing the source of the event:

```
@FXML
void addMoreButton(ActionEvent event) {
    Button source = (Button) event.getSource();
    source.setOnAction(null); // remove event handler

    Button newButton = new Button("+");
    newButton.setOnAction(this::addMoreButton);

    vboxTest.getChildren().add(newButton);
}
```

**Note:** I left out the list/array on purpose since the array restricts the number of elements (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`) and should result in an exception for containing `null`/a value already in the child list, unless you set the array size to 1 which allows you to do one call. Of course you could save those `Button`s in a list, if other code requires you to do this.

Not sure if removing the event handler is the desired result. Different things like inserting the new button after the one clicked could also be done:

```
@FXML
void addMoreButton(ActionEvent event) {
    Node source = (Node) event.getSource();

    Button newButton = new Button("+");
    newButton.setOnAction(this::addMoreButton);

    vboxTest.getChildren().add(vboxTest.getChildren().indexOf(source) + 1, newButton);
}
```

Comment: Its magical Solution! Both can fulfill my requirements. Have no words for your such help. Thanks Alot